# Parallax Opening and Closing Photo

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, parallax

I am working on a website that uses parallax- I have a photo that I sliced in half vertically and when you scroll down it separates. In other words, there is no sign that the photo will "open" until you scroll. Here is my code:

```
    $("#section5_back5").stop().animate({ right : (520 * object_speed * 1.8) + (scroll_position * object_speed)}, delay);
    $("#section5_back5").stop().animate({ top : (-50 * object_speed2) + (scroll_position * object_speed2)}, delay);
    $("#section5_back6").stop().animate({ left : (545 * object_speed * 1.8) + (scroll_position * object_speed)}, delay);
    $("#section5_back6").stop().animate({ top : (-50 * object_speed2) + (scroll_position * object_speed2)}, delay);
}
```

Is there a way to "close" the pic back about 100px after you reach the bottom of the photo?

Comment: I would make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so that people can tinker around. You can add dummy images using [lorempixel](http://lorempixel.com).